# Is it possible to use destructuring while function call?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'd like to use destructuring right inside a constructor call like this:

```
signup: async (userInfo) => {
    const user = new User({ email, password, privacyPolicyConsent, username } = userInfo);
}
```

But params are undefined.

I want to prevent from injection of undesirable params by redeclaration, therefore I don't want to pass whole object like this:

```
signup: async (userInfo) => {
    const user = new User(userInfo);
}
```

For now my working solution is as follow:

```
signup: async (userInfo) => {
    const { email, password, privacyPolicyConsent, username } = userInfo;
    const user = new User({ email, password, privacyPolicyConsent, username });
}
```

But I got a feeling I could write this part in a better way. Did I miss something? Any advice regarding best practices appreciated.

Comment: `want to prevent from injection of undesirable params by redeclaration` so far you don't do anything with that "additional params" there is no security issue

Comment: The `User` function constructor is the place for this, not the function call.

Comment: FWIW, passing around objects *abstracts* logic. Perhaps in the future you will want to extend what info goes into `userInfo`. You just need to redefine `userInfo` for that and make the `User` class aware of what to do with the additional data. But if you destructure your object at several points in the "plumbing code" in-between, that'll be a lot more work…

Comment: I mean userInfo is an object which comes from request body directly. If I pass it directly to the constructor - it could cause security issues, that is why I want to redeclare.

Comment: Why can't `User` take care of its own security needs?

Comment: The function constructor can have your de-structuring `function({ email, password, privacyPolicyConsent, username }={})` .... and no other parameters are passed...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can Destruct it directly, like the following

```
signup: async ({ email, password, privacyPolicyConsent, username }) => {
    const user = new User(email,password,privacyPolicyConsent,userName);
}
signUp(userInfo);
```

**UPDATE**

This will prevent to handle destruct error if it is sent undefined
so you need to check for userInfo before you send it

`if(userInfo) signUp(userInfo);`

**UPDATE 2**

if you dont want to check for userInfo if it is undefined 
you can assign a default value in method level like following

```
signup: async ({ email, password, privacyPolicyConsent, username }={}) => {
        const user = new User(email,password,privacyPolicyConsent,userName);
    }
```

Comment: tip: using `= {}` as a default will prevent destructuring errors when `userInfo` is not supplied.

Comment: this one will destruct any userInfo, if it is not supplied then they will be undefined

Comment: `TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'email' of 'undefined' or 'null'.` if you call `signup()`

Comment: Yes you are right they will throw an error  thanks for correcting me

Comment: Sorry, wasn't trying to correct you! Just noting something I found useful because its difficult to handle the error elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Ooh so would I.

This is what I tend to do (an immediately invoked function):

```
signup: async userInfo => {
  const user = new User((({ email, password, privacyPolicyConsent, username }) =>
    ({ email, password, privacyPolicyConsent, username })
  ))(userInfo));
}
```

It reduces it to one statement, but doesn't remove the problem of duplicated (and ugly) code.

---

Maybe a function to do it might be best practices:

```
const dstr = (obj, ...keys) => keys.reduce((o, k) => { o[k] = obj[k]; return o; }, {});

// ...

const user = dstr(userInfo, email, password, privacyPolicyConsent, username);
```

Or you could use that reduce method to create it inline :)

Intrigued what alternatives there are.

(EDIT) The above is assuming that you can't destructure the object beforehand.